# Sign up with email or mobile number ,how to design the user table?

Tags: mobile

Our website will allow the user to sign up with email address or international mobile number.

How should i design the user table to store the international mobile number?
   Split the mobile number into country code and other part?

Comment: have a seperate section for country code and mobile no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should i design the user table to store the international mobile
>   number? Split the mobile number into country code and other part?

Yes. Many websites will actually make you choose your country from a drop down list. Store that separately from the number, and then validate the number front-end, with backend enforcement.

**Edit:**

You can see an example at the bottom here:

https://www.virgin-atlantic.com/en/us/frequentflyer/joinnow/index.jsp?media_code=GLO